# find x and y location of window pane using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, win32gui

I'm trying to find the relative location of the mouse when I click inside of a specific window pane. That is - to be clear, I need to get the X and Y position of a mouse click within a window. I do not need the XY position of the mouse on the screen (as I can already get that). I basically need the location of the window pane of interest. I can calculate the relative XY from there. The code below simulates what I think the proposed solution is. I've tried importing win32gui but it doesn't work in python 64bit. Is there some other way of getting the x and y locations of a window pane from Microsoft? My code I think will look something like this:

```
#### start of code #####
from pynput.mouse import Listener

# part I don't know how to do######
X_ofwindow, Y_ofwindow = microsoftwindow(x1,y1)
###############################################

def on_click (x,y, button, pressed):
    x_relative_to_window = x - X_ofwindow
    y_relative_to_window = y  - Y_ofwindow


with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: have you tried selenium?

Comment: I have not. That looks to be for web development correct? I'm looking to the XY location of any pane I happen to open in Microsoft OS, rather than opening something built or generated in python. Not against trying it btw, just not sure that's as generic as what I'm looking for.

Comment: oh i see. ya it is. so you are asking for os cursor positioning

Comment: Yes! The code above gets me the os cursor position, but, it returns the X and Y of the screen. Not of any particular window.

Comment: ok so i feel like i am misunderstanding what you mean by window. like for instance if Chrome is open is it considered a window?

Comment: pynput.mouse actually returns the X and Y for me. But it's not valuable to me unless I know the X and Y of the screen I'm working in also. Since window panes can move, unless I position my window pane in the same exact location every time I turn on my computer, it wont work.

Comment: Yes, Chrome would be a window. Any application really.

Comment: so you are not asking for the x, y position on the screen but the x, y within a window such as chrome

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: what application are you trying to click on or what are you attempting to do with your above script

Comment: I'm attempting to digitize a graph,from an image, mind you.

Comment: so like take an image of a graph and turn it into a python graph?

Comment: my personal suggestion is to maximize the window to the dimension of the screen then work from there. based on the documentation, i do not see any support for selecting specific windows

Comment: More like export the values to an excel file. Science kind of stuff.